# Can Megalodon have the strength to sink the Titanic?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, fauna

Does  Megalodon have the strength required to sink the RMS Titanic?

Comment: In what context? Knock it over? Take a bite out of it? Be dropped onto it at terminal velocity via orbital delivery?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You may not be aware, but the Stack Exchange network of sites is dedicated to specific questions and answers and is divided into categories of expertise. Here at Worldbuilding, we focus on the development of new (or altered) worlds.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no apparent Worldbuilding application.

Answer (score 2):

Megalalodon grew to around 20 meters long and weighed around 100 metric tons. That's a lot of fish!

However Titanic was 166 meters long and the hull was made from rolled steel from 2.5cm to 3.5cm thick.

If it did a serious ramming attack on titanic it's entirely plausible that Megaladon would rupture the hull plates and cause a significant leak. However it would also do considerable injury to itself. Ramming your nose into solid steel hurts!

Because of the Titanic's design a single hole would not suffice, there were multiple compartments in the ship and you would need to breach 5 of them. You would also need to breach them all strongly enough to overwhelm the pumps trying to take the water out.

It's not realistic that even something as big as Megalodon could achieve that without first seriously injuring itself, especially since it would not know where the compartments were or even that it needed to breach them.

Comment: Titanic could stay afloat with four compartments breached. When in the real world history accident five compartments were breached, her fate was sealed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanic#Sinking

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks, I thought it was 4 for some reason. I've fixed it :)

Comment: I knew the specifics were mentioned in the movie, so I figured Wikipedia probably had the true figures. From there it was just a matter of finding them in the article.